# Can't find correct data types in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sqldatatypes

Before asking my question, I have to say that I am a begginner to mysql.

I have a csv file of network traffic with the following structure that I want to store in MariaDB:

```
No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Length","Info"
"1","0.000000","192.168.1.254","192.168.1.83","TCP","66","2259  >  34951 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=509 Len=0 TSval=3722246587 TSecr=1268347869"
"2","0.000001","192.168.1.254","192.168.1.83","TCP","70","2259  >  34951 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=509 Len=4 TSval=3722246588 TSecr=1268347869"
"3","0.000013","192.168.1.83","192.168.1.254","TCP","66","34951  >  2259 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=5 Win=502 Len=0 TSval=1268347874 TSecr=3722246588"
"4","0.000572","192.168.1.83","192.168.1.254","TCP","87","34951  >  2259 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=5 Win=502 Len=21 TSval=1268347875 TSecr=3722246588"
"5","0.000709","192.168.1.83","192.168.1.254","TCP","68","34951  >  2259 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=22 Ack=5 Win=502 Len=2 TSval=1268347875 TSecr=3722246588"
"6","0.001151","192.168.1.83","192.168.1.254","TCP","74","56341  >  2259 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1268347876 TSecr=0 WS=128"
"7","0.011318","192.168.1.254","192.168.1.83","TCP","66","2259  >  34951 [ACK] Seq=5 Ack=22 Win=509 Len=0 TSval=3722246593 TSecr=1268347875"
"8","0.011319","192.168.1.254","192.168.1.83","TCP","74","2259  >  56341 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65160 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3722246593 TSecr=1268347876 WS=128"
"9","0.011319","192.168.1.254","192.168.1.83","TCP","66","2259  >  34951 [FIN, ACK] Seq=5 Ack=25 Win=509 Len=0 TSval=3722246594 TSecr=1268347875"
"10","0.011343","192.168.1.83","192.168.1.254","TCP","66","56341  >  2259 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1268347886 TSecr=3722246593"
```

To know the type of data of the columns, I have ran the df.info() and this is the result:

```
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   No.          6887 non-null   int64  
 1   Time         6887 non-null   float64
 2   Source       6887 non-null   object 
 3   Destination  6887 non-null   object 
 4   Protocol     6887 non-null   object 
 5   Length       6887 non-null   int64  
 6   Info         6887 non-null   object
```

Therefore, I store the data in a table named table_prueba with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE table_prueba (
    -> id BIGINT,
    -> Time FLOAT,
    -> IP_source JSON,
    -> IP_destination JSON,
    -> Protocol  JSON,
    -> Length BIGINT,
    -> Info JSON,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
```

Then, the csv file is stored in this table with the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Desktop/Honeypot/Prueba.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE table_prueba
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES
    -> (id,Time, IP_source, IP_destination,Protocol,Length,Info);
```

But the following errors appear:

```
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"1"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 1         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.000000"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 1 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 1    |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"2"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 2         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.000001"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 2 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"70"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 2    |
| Warning | 4025 | CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.Info` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`                       |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"3"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 2         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.000013"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 2 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 2    |
| Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'                                                   |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"4"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 3         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.000572"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 3 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"87"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 3    |
| Warning | 4025 | CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.Info` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`                       |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"5"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 3         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.000709"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 3 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"68"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 3    |
| Warning | 4025 | CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.Info` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`                       |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"6"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 3         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.001151"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 3 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"74"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 3    |
| Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'                                                   |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"7"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 4         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.011318"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 4 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 4    |
| Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'                                                   |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"8"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 5         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.011319"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 5 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"74"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 5    |
| Warning | 4025 | CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.Info` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`                       |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"9"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 5         |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.011319"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 5 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 5    |
| Warning | 4025 | CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.Info` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`                       |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"10"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 5        |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.011343"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 5 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 5    |
| Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'                                                   |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"11"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 6        |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.011423"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 6 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 6    |
| Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'                                                   |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"12"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 7        |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.011900"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 7 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"80"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 7    |
| Warning | 4025 | CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.Info` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`                       |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"13"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 7        |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.019983"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 7 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 7    |
| Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'                                                   |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"14"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 8        |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.019984"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 8 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"70"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 8    |
| Warning | 4025 | CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.Info` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`                       |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"15"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 8        |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.019996"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 8 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 8    |
| Warning | 1062 | Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'                                                   |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"16"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 9        |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect double value: '"0.020773"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Time` at row 9 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"110"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`Length` at row 9   |
| Warning | 4025 | CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.Info` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`                       |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '"17"' for column `Prueba`.`table_prueba`.`id` at row 9
```

I would really appreciate your help because although I have tried with multiple data types in the definition of the table, I can't find the correct ones.

Comment: Don't you need to add `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` ([see docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/)) to the `LOAD DATA` statement so it knows that fields are surrounded by quotes?

Comment: You have easier solutions to do that using phpmyadmin if you have it.

Comment: Don't use JSON for the string columns, use VARCHAR.

Comment: @kmoser if I use it it gives me the following error: CONSTRAINT `table_prueba.IP_source` failed for `Prueba`.`table_prueba`

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use the JSON datatype. JSON requires the values to be in quotes, but the quotes are being used for the CSV syntax, not as literal parts of the values.

Comment: @Barmar So then which data type should I use?

Comment: I said before: VARCHAR

Comment: `No` - BIGINT. `Time` - DECIMAL(10,6). `Source`,`Destination`,`Protocol` - VARCHAR(15), `Length` - SMALLINT, `Info` - VARCHAR(255). Maybe adjust max. length for Time and Info. And `.. FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ..`. Also I recommend you to rename `Time` and `Length` (these words are keywords which may result in problems). And I'd use input preprocessing, INET_ATON() function and INT column for Ipv4 addresses

Comment: @Akina That worked!!  But could you explained a little bit more why varchar(255) must be used? Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: *why varchar(255) must be used?* Not must but may, you may easily alter its length. #1. This is the longest VARCHAR which uses 1 byte for data length (i.e. making the column shorter makes no sense). #2. The data looks like firewall log, and I doubt that extra info may be longer.

Comment: Source and Destination should be INET6

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `DOUBLE` for `time`, else large values will be rounded to about 7 significant digits (for `FLOAT`.

Thos strings are not "JSON"; use `VARCHAR(100)` (or some suitable max len).

IP addresses should be `VARCHAR(39)` to handle both IPv4 and IPv6.  But if you will be testing them for anything other than "=", say so.  Storing IP addresses as strings can't be used in range tests.